# Orientation of a simple, closed, piecewise regular, parametrized curve

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

In [Do Carmo's "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces"](https://books.google.com/books/about/Differential_Geometry_of_Curves_and_Surf.html?id=1v0YAQAAIAAJ&source=kp_book_description), in **Chapter 4-5** on Gauss-Bonnet he states:

> It can be shown that one of the two possible orientations of $\alpha$ makes it positively oriented

From this paragraph and figure:

[image]

About a simple, closed, piecewise regular parametrized curve $\alpha:I\rightarrow S$ in a surface $S$.
In this case, positively oriented means, for each $\alpha(t)$ belonging to a regular arc, the positive orthogonal basis $\{\alpha'(t),h(t)\}$ satisfies the condition that for any curve $\beta:I \rightarrow R$ with $\beta(0)=\alpha(t)$ and $\beta'(0)=\alpha'(t)$ we have $\langle \beta'(0),h(t)\rangle > 0$.
But how would one go about showing this? Intuitively I know what the definition means but I cannot apply it.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> Without more context it's hard to answer, but the issue likely boils down to: 1. A path on an interval has precisely two orientations; 2. On an oriented surface, a closed curve is either "compatible" or "incompatible" with the surface orientation; 3. Reversing the orientation of a path "toggles compatibility" with the surface orientation.

Comment: Sorry, I'll add more context. My problem is proving the statement using the given definition for positively oriented.

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood the meaning of $\textit{positively oriented}$. For $\{\alpha'(t),h(t)\}$ it means that $(\alpha'(t) \wedge h(t)) N > 0$, right? Otherwise it doesn't really make sense to define this for a surface.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit, I really appreciate it. I am new here and haven't figured everything out yet.

Comment: Correction: I mean $\textit{positive orthogonal basis}$ in the third comment, not $\textit{positively oriented}$.